# If the goal is to fail what will it be called if we succeed in it?

Tags: logic

If a person's goal is to fail and if he has succeeded in it, will it be said you have failed?

Comment: Can you share a little bit more about what might have made this an interesting problem for you?

Comment: Just curious to know.

Answer (score 3):

To me it sounds like just inaccurate speech, not like a paradox.

I can imagine someone who has the goal to fail his math exam, and succeeds in doing so.

Using "succeed" and "fail" in a general sense makes the sentence not well founded, at least.

Comment: Right. There is no paradox unless succeed and fail are used in exactly the same sense. If they aren't, it's in equivocation. If they are, it's a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a variant of the liar paradox, cf. http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liar-paradox